# Don't know where is error. Code returns False with no reason

Tags: python

can you tell me, why this code returns False? I've just started learning python and have no clue why this doesn't work.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from math import *
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}

def average(numbers):
    total = sum(numbers)
    total = float(total)
    total = total / len(numbers)
    return total

def get_average(students):
    homework = average(students["homework"])
    quizzes = average(students["quizzes"])
    tests = average(students["tests"])
    homework = homework * 0.1
    quizzes = quizzes * 0.3
    tests =  tests * 0.6
    score = tests + quizzes + homework
    score = float(score)
    return score

def get_letter_grade(score):
    score = float(score)
    if score == int or score == float:
        if score >= 90:
            return "A"
        elif score >= 80:
            return "B"
        elif score >= 70:
            return "C"
        elif score >= 60:
            return "D"
        else:
            return "F"
    else:
        return False

print get_letter_grade(get_average(lloyd))
```

Thank you in advance ;)

Comment: Because score isnt `float`, it is an instance of `float`.

Comment: Please post the code here, with that said the condition `if score == int or score == float` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: What is `score == float` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to the attempted type comparison, the line:

```
score = float(score)
```

converts whatever `score` is to a float. Checking to see what type `score` is after that is pointless - it *must* be a float. If `score` can not be converted to a float a `ValueError` exception would be thrown, and the subsequent code would not be executed at all.

Having said that I think that you meant this for the type comparison:

```
if type(score) == int or type(score) == float:
```

which will work because you are comparing the *type* of `score` to the *type* `int/float`. However, it is preferable (because `isinstance()` takes inheritance into account) to perform the check like this:

```
if isinstance(score, (int, float)):
```

but, as I said at the beginning, type checking is not required because at the point of the check the variable *must* be a float.

You could rewrite the function to use a `try/except` block like this:

```
def get_letter_grade(score):
    try:
        score = float(score)
        if score >= 90:
            return "A"
        elif score >= 80:
            return "B"
        elif score >= 70:
            return "C"
        elif score >= 60:
            return "D"
        else:
            return "F"
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Comment: Great, no problem. If that solved your problem then you should accept this answer, or one of the others if you think that better answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in:

```
if score == int or score == float:
```

What you want is:

```
if isinstance(score, (int, float)):
```

Your variable `score` will never be equal to class `int` or class `float`. But it can be an instance of `int` or `float`.

Another valid variant is:

```
if type(score) is int or type(score) is float:
```

or:

```
if type(score) in (int, float):
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the type this way

```
if type(score) == int or type(score) == float:
```

instead of

```
if score == int or score == float:
```

as score is value not type itself, so it will always return false.

Also, you can remove this if, as you convert it to float anyway. This is the safer way:

```
def get_letter_grade(score):
    try:
        score = float(score)

        if score >= 90:
            return "A"
        elif score >= 80:
            return "B"
        elif score >= 70:
            return "C"
        elif score >= 60:
            return "D"
        else:
            return "F"
    except ValueError:
        print("score is not an number")
        return false
```

Comment: Other answers already explained all this. What does you answer add?